# Проблема использования метода PUT в веб приложении Java, Spring Restfull

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Доброго времени суток. У меня возникла проблема при реализации изменения данных в моём веб приложении. Код:
class UserController

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAll(){
        ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("main");
        mov.addObject("users", userService.getAllUsers());
        return mov;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addView(){
        ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("add");
        mov.addObject("user",  new User());
        return mov;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getUser(@PathVariable(value = "userId") Integer userId){
        ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("update");
        mov.addObject("user", userService.getUserById(userId));
        return mov;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
        userService.addUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{userId}")
    public ModelAndView delUser(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId){
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView updUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        userService.updateUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
    }



}
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>UserControl</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

application-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.malashenko.usercontrol.*"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.malashenko.usercontrol.repository"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <bean id="hibernateExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <!--<prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Set base package of your entities -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.malashenko.usercontrol.*"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="springLiquibaseBean" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:liquibase/usercontrol-liquibase.xml"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

main.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf8"
         pageEncoding="utf8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Панель пользователей</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/main.js"></script>

    <style>
        <%@include file='resources/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/main.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/jquery-ui.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/jquery-ui.structure.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/jquery-ui.theme.css' %>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tableUsers">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <td><input id="add" name="add" type="button"  value="+"
                               onclick="javascript:window.location='/users/addUser'"></th></td>
                <td>Фамилия</td>
                <td>Логин</td>
                <td>Пароль</td>
                <td>О себе</td>
                <td>Адрес</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="del" name="delete" type="button"  value=" "
                                    onclick="javascript:window.location='/users/delete/'+ '${user.id}'">
                        <input id="upd" name="update" type="button"  value=" "
                               onclick="javascript:window.location='/users/'+ '${user.id}'">
                    </td>
                    <td>${user.surname}</td>
                    <td>${user.login}</td>
                    <td>${user.password}</td>
                    <td>${user.info}</td>
                    <td>${user.address}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

update.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf8"
         pageEncoding="utf8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Панель пользователей</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" c:url value="resources/js/localization.js"></script>

    <style>
        <%@include file='resources/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/main.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/jquery-ui.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/jquery-ui.structure.css' %>
        <%@include file='resources/css/jquery-ui.theme.css' %>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="/users/update" commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="surname">
                <spring:message text="Фамилия"/>
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="surname" value='${user.surname}'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="login">
                <spring:message text="Логин"/>
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="login" value='${user.login}'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="password">
                <spring:message text="Пароль"/>
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="password" value='${user.password}'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="info">
                <spring:message text="О себе"/>
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="info" value='${user.info}'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address">
                <spring:message text="Адрес"/>
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address" value='${user.address}'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                                   value="<spring:message text="Изменить"/>"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Я передаю свой объект из main.jsp в update. Потом я меня информацию и мне надо его обновить. Выскакивает ошибка томката

HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

Type Status Report

Message Request method 'POST' not supported

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

Помогите плиз справиться с этой бедой

Answer (score 1):

вы передаете методом POST

```
<form:form method="post" action="/users/update" commandName="user">
```

а на принимающей стороне (контроллере) есть инструкции только для метода PUT

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView updUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    userService.updateUser(user);
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/users"));
}
```

определитесь какой метод хотите использовать.
Об этом же вам сказал томкат

`Message Request method 'POST' not supported` - Сообщения с методом POST не поддерживаются

Comment: в jsp я не могу выбрать метод PUT к сожалению

Comment: @NightWolf почему?  и как вы тогда собираетесь отправлять запрос POST  а слушать PUT ?

Comment: @Kirill Stoianov я написал put в jsp, таже ошибка. Не видит jsp такого метода

Comment: Вы и не сможете отправлять другими методами кроме как POST,GET из формы. Тут 2 решения. 1 Изменить метод на один из выше упомянутых. 2 Отправлять данные через ajax request.

Comment: @GVArt можно ещё использовать [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html)